# Access VBA Importing CSV File and Working With Record Sets

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access, import

I'm trying to import a **massive** CSV file (1.2 GB) into Access.  I'm aware Access caps out at 2 GB.  Really we don't even need the entire file, but I'm trying to pull in certain rows for every record.  If necessary we can use SQL Server Express as the back-end, but I'm trying to do this all in Access.

Below is the code I've worked up so far.  This actually works until I get an error: "there was an error 9: Subscript out of range".  For the file I was testing I noticed it imported the first 29 rows.  So at first I was thinking it was a bad character, extra carriage return, something like that.  However I opened the file in Notepad++ and didn't see anything suspicious.  So I deleted the first 29 rows from the file and imported again.  Now I got about 400 some rows before getting the same error.  Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

If you have suggestions about redoing my import method, I'm open if you can give me a good working example.  I was reading about File System Objects, but didn't really see an entire example of importing a file and inputting desired fields into a table.  You can see the first method I tried in the commented out section at the bottom of the code.  This method failed because the MyData variable ran out of space for the STRING.

FOLLOW UP:  I implemented a few of the changes mentioned in the comments.  The issue is coming in during the "For Each X In rs.Fields' loop.  I declared X as an object.  Current loop is at the top of the code below.  I changed it slightly so that it checks if X is not NULL, however now I'm getting a 424 error: object required.  I'm confused by this, because I don't understand how we get into the For loop if there isn't another X.

FOLLOW UP 2: I'm using the split function because each row is contained within one cell.  I'm not sure that it's correct that I'm saying the file is delimited in the connection string.  I've noticed I'm hitting the issue when the recordset pulls back multiple values.  There's no column headers, so I'm usually just getting "F1" for each recordset.  However when I'm having the issue, the recordset is pulling back two fields, F1 and F2, and F2 is NULL.  I really don't need to loop for each field in a recordset, I know I always just want the first one.  How would I do that instead of "For Each fld in rs.Fields"

```
Do While Not rs.EOF
    For Each x In rs.Fields
        If X Is Not Null Then
            tmpData = Split(x.Value, ";")
            SQL = "INSERT INTO TestMaster(BPARTNER, [CACONT_ACC], UCCONTRACT, [SITE_CITY_1]) SELECT " & tmpData(0) & "," & tmpData(1) & "," & tmpData(2) & ", '" & tmpData(5) & "'"
            DoCmd.RunSQL (SQL)
        End If
        N = N + 1
     Next
    rs.MoveNext
Loop



Private Sub ImportMaster_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim MyData As String
Dim tmpData() As String
Dim N As Long

N = 1

'close tables/queries to prevent potential errors
Call CloseAll(False, False, True, True)

'Select Excel file
Dim FileName As Variant
FileName = selectFile
If Format(FileName) = vbNullString Then
    'Canceled
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim sPath As String
sPath = Left(FileName, InStrRev(FileName, "\"))
Dim sFileName As String
sFileName = Dir(FileName)


'open the please wait form
DoCmd.OpenForm ("Please Wait")

Dim rs As Object
Dim cn As Object
Dim SQL As String
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


cn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
               "Data Source= " & sPath & _
               ";Extended Properties=""text; HDR=No; FMT=Delimited(;);""")
rs.Open "Select * from " & sFileName, cn

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Do While Not rs.EOF
    For Each x In rs.Fields

        tmpData = Split(x.Value, ";")
        If tmpData(0) <> "" Then
        SQL = "INSERT INTO TestMaster(BPARTNER, [CACONT_ACC], UCCONTRACT, [SITE_CITY_1]) SELECT " & tmpData(0) & "," & tmpData(1) & "," & tmpData(2) & ", '" & tmpData(5) & "'"
        DoCmd.RunSQL (SQL)
        End If
        N = N + 1
     Next
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

DoCmd.SetWarnings True


    'Open FileName For Binary As #1

'MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
'Get #1, , MyData
'Close #1
'strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

'For I = LBound(strData) To 2 'UBound(strData)   --changed to 2 for t3esting, should be UBound
    'If Len(Trim(strData(I))) <> 0 Then
        'tmpData = Split(strData(I), ";")

        'ResultArray(N, 0) = Replace(tmpData(5), Chr(34), "")
        'ResultArray(N, 1) = Replace(tmpData(1), Chr(34), "")
        'ResultArray(N, 2) = Replace(tmpData(2), Chr(34), "")
        'ResultArray(N, 3) = Replace(tmpData(3), Chr(34), "")

        'N = N + 1
    'End If
'Next I
```

Comment: (1) Make sure you use 'Option Explicit' and compile everything. (2) In your error trap, you can try to display the row of data, but like you say, you may not see anything.  Add an optional 'Resume' in the trap (i.e. "If err.number = 9 then" and "Resume". Place breakpoint on Resume. Examine your 'Split' result.  Finally, if you can't see bad data, it can still exist as a non-printable character, so write a loop in the trap to spin thru each character and display like "Debug.Print Mid(tmpData,ix,1) & vbtab & Asc(Mid(tmpData,ix,1))

Comment: While debugging I would remove the error handler (or set `On Error Goto 0`), so the code is stopped for debugging and reading variables when the error occurs.

Comment: And you should check `UBound(tmpData)` before trying to access `tmpData(5)` - that would be my guess for causing "Subscript out of range".

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm still having issues though.  I've updated my original comment with the progress.

Comment: Your additional checking is wise, but it should be like this: `If Not IsNull(x) Then`... Also check the result of the `Split` operation before assuming it has as many entries as you later assume.

Comment: Your file is semi-colon delimited, so how come you're splitting on ";" within your field loop?  Does your file have quoted (escaped) fields containing ";" ?

Comment: Please post example few rows of content.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, but you can consider this closed (is there a way to actually close a question on here?).  It was a problem with the original file.  On a hunch I ended up doing a text to columns split on a portion of the original CSV.  When I did this I got a warning about overwriting text in existing columns.  I might have to go to IT and see how they are generating this file.  Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try some extra checking:

```
tmpData = Split(x.Value, ";")
if UBound(tmpData)<5 then
    debug.print "At N=" & N & " there is a line with too few semicolons."
else
    SQL = "INSERT INTO TestMaster(BPARTNER, [CACONT_ACC], UCCONTRACT, [SITE_CITY_1]) SELECT " & tmpData(0) & "," & tmpData(1) & "," & tmpData(2) & ", '" & tmpData(5) & "'"
    DoCmd.RunSQL (SQL)
end if
```

And, if you are iterating over GBs of data as you say, it is probably wise to have some of these statements littered throughout the loops:

```
DoEvents
```

Comment: The problem is I'm not even hitting that split function.  See my 2nd follow up in the original comment.